# Indefinite integral vs definite integral: Why the different answers?

Tags: integration

When I try to evaluate the indefinite integral of this function

${{\rm e}^{ \left( s+1 \right) r}}\sin \left( r \right)$,

I get this

${\frac {{{\rm e}^{ \left( s+1 \right) r}} \left( \sin \left( r
 \right) s+\sin \left( r \right) -\cos \left( r \right)  \right) }{{s}
^{2}+2\,s+2}}
$.

But when evaluate the same function over an interval `[0, r]` I end up with

${\frac {{{\rm e}^{ \left( s+1 \right) r}}\sin \left( r \right) s+{
{\rm e}^{ \left( s+1 \right) r}}\sin \left( r \right) -{{\rm e}^{
 \left( s+1 \right) r}}\cos \left( r \right) +1}{{s}^{2}+2\,s+2}}
$.

The difference of the two output is $- \left( {s}^{2}+2\,s+2 \right) ^{-1}$, which I think should be zero.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Are you integrating with respect to $s$ or $r$?

Comment: Sorry about this confusion. I am integrating with respect to $r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing the indefinite integral you missed one vital detail: the constant of integration. Forgetting the constant of integration leads exactly to the kind of problem you have here. Therefore: don't forget the constant of integration.

Note that while $(s^2 + 2s + 2)^{-1}$ doesn't *seem* like a constant, it *is* a constant with respect to $r$, and that is what matters.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the indefinite integral must be ${\frac {{{\rm e}^{ \left( s+1 \right) r}} \left( \sin \left( r
 \right) s+\sin \left( r \right) -\cos \left( r \right)  \right) +C}{{s}
^{2}+2\,s+2}}
$?

Comment: Indeed, if $F(r)$ is the indefinite integral given above, then $F(0)=-(s^2+2s+2)^{-1}$. So the definite integral is $F(r)-F(0)$.

Comment: @MMM Or $\frac {{{\rm e}^{ \left( s+1 \right) r}} \left( \sin \left( r  \right) s+\sin \left( r \right) -\cos \left( r \right)  \right) }{{s} ^{2}+2\,s+2}+D$. They amount to the same thing. Note that if $s$ is a variable too, then $C$ and $D$ are functions of $s$.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks indeed!

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Thanks Indeed!